# How can I disable temporarily Cisco AnyConnect user from ASDM?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, firewall, cisco-anyconnect

I created user under local users. Now I need to disable the user connecting through VPN for a while only.

Platform is ASA 5512 with ASDM 7.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### From ASDM:

1. Choose Configuration > Remote Access VPN > AAA/Local Users > Local Users.
2. Select the user you want to configure and click Edit.
3. In the left-hand pane, click VPN Policy.
4. Specify the number of simultaneous logins by the user as 0 (zero).

### From the CLI:

```
username mydisableduser attributes
 vpn-simultaneous-logins 0
```